# why does angular animation within directive execute on page load?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-animation

I have an angular ngSwitch animation applied in 2 different ways, one within a directive, and one on the html page. The animation within the directive fires on page load. Why is this occurring and how to fix?

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/japvWhohw8JaDWkDBUAf?p=preview

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body id="ng-app" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
    <a href="#" ng-click="myVal = !myVal">Change value</a>
    <br><br>

    <span><strong>Through directive</strong><small> - animation fires on page load</small></span>
    <div value-rotate="myVal" style=""></div>

    <br>
    <span><strong>Not through directive</strong><small> - animation does no fire on page load</small></span><br>
    <span class="value-rotate" ng-switch on="myVal">
      <div class="value-rotate__value" ng-switch-when="true">value is {{ myVal }}</div>
      <div class="value-rotate__value" ng-switch-when="false">value is {{ myVal }}</div>
    </span>

  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', ['valueRotate'])

.controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myVal = true; 
});

angular.module('valueRotate', ['ngAnimate'])
  .directive('valueRotate',  function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        value: '=valueRotate'
      },
      templateUrl: 'value-rotate.html',
      link: function (scope, element) {
        element.css({ position: 'relative', overflow: 'hidden' });
      }
    };
  });
```

style.css

```
.value-rotate {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.value-rotate__value {
  padding: 10px;
}

.value-rotate__value.ng-animate {
  -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) 0.5s;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.value-rotate__value.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.value-rotate__value.ng-enter {
  top: -50px;
}

.value-rotate__value.ng-leave,
.value-rotate__value.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  top: 0;
}
```

value-rotate.html (directive template)

```
<span class="value-rotate" ng-switch on="value">
  <div class="value-rotate__value" ng-switch-when="true">value is {{ value }}</div>
  <div class="value-rotate__value" ng-switch-when="false">value is {{ value }}</div>
</span>
```

Comment: I believe that what happens is value in directive changes from 'undefinded' to true on first load and it does animate then, i'm just starting weekend but will look for solution from home, cheers

Comment: The real question is why it shouldn't?

Comment: So any element with an animation within a directive will fire on page load? Say you use this element in multiple places on your page, you would have one heck on an animation party on page load.

Comment: You have your CSS transitions on ng-animate when they shouldn't be. They should be on ng-leave and ng-enter instead.

Comment: @pixelbits, tried your solution in my plunder example but did not change the outcome.